# trying to add a sticky menu to wordpress website

Tags: css, menu, sticky

with the following CSS I managed to create a sticky menu on my wordpress website. Unfortunately, my menu now overlaps the titles on all pages. how do I manage to separate my menu and content so all the content start underneath the menu?

```css
#header-grid {
    background:#fff;
    height:60px;
    z-index:170;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=header-grid>
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] please. Not a single div

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of `class=""` use `id=""`
- Instead of `absolute` or `fixed` (which will overlap), use:

```css
position: sticky;
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

body {
  height: 300vh;
  border: 4px dashed #000;
}

#header-grid {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 170;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-grid">HEADER</div>
Page content
```